# Why can't you randomize an advice string to show that $P/poly \subseteq NP$

Tags: complexity-theory

**Definitions:**

1.
$$\mathsf{NP} = \{S \: \mid \: \text{Exists a polynomial, non-deterministic algorithm $A$ s.t. $A$ decides $S$} \}$$ Where a polynomial non-deterministic algorithm, is an algorithm that it's runtime is bounded by $p$ some polynomial, and may behave differently from run to run.

2. $$\mathsf{P/poly} = \bigcup_{c=0}^\infty \mathsf{P/} n^c$$ We say a problem $S \in \mathsf{P}/l$ for some function $l\colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, if there exists a polynomial algorithm A and an infinite set of strings $\{a_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ s.t.:

   a. $\forall n\colon \left | a_n \right | = l(n)$

   b. $\forall x\colon x \in S \Leftrightarrow A(a_{\left | x \right |},x) = 1$

**Question:**

Given $S \in \mathsf{P/poly}$, why is it not possible to show an algorithm $M$ that randomizes an advice string $a_{\left | x\right |}$ such that $\left | a_{\left | x\right |} \right | \leq p(\left | x \right |)$, and returns the output of $A(a_{\left | x\right |},x)$? Formally it should perform as follows:

1. Set $a_{\left | x\right |}$ = ""
2. While $\left | a_{\left | x\right |} \right | \leq p(\left | x \right |)$ choose non-deterministically:

   a. $a \leftarrow a0$

   b. $a \leftarrow a1$

   c. Continue to step 3
3. Return $A(a_{\left | x\right |},x)$

I understand that $\mathsf{P/poly} \not \subseteq \mathsf{NP}$ because it contains non-decidable problems, but can't understand why this proof fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following functions with advice:
$$ f(a,x) = a. $$
(The advice $a$ is one bit.)

The function $f$ is computable in polynomial time, and this shows that any language of the form $\{ x : |x| \in S \}$ belongs to $\mathsf{P/poly}$. If we choose $S$ to be some uncomputable set, then the corresponding language is not in $\mathsf{NP}$.

If you run your proposed algorithm on $f$, then you obtain a nondeterministic algorithm which accepts *all* strings. The problem is that $f$ is guaranteed to compute the language given the correct advice, but there is no guarantee as to what happens when it is fed the wrong advice.